# cURL Ruby Library

Tags: ruby, curl, libcurl

Are there any *active* [`cURL`](http://curl.haxx.se) libraries for Ruby?

Comment: @c00lrguy I've considered it. Not sure that I've got the experience to create a wrapper for `cURL` though. Mainly because of cURL's complexity.

Comment: @c00lryguy, Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) and [Typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus). I've used them both and they're very powerful and easy to use. Both support parallel connections well.

There's also [Patron](https://github.com/toland/patron) but I haven't used it lately and don't know if it's under active support.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll give Patron a go.